# Failed to deploy ruby app to heroku "Precompling assets failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bitbucket, web-deployment

I've tried to deploy a Rails app to Heroku using Bitbucket, however, it shows an error that my ruby app can not compile.

[image]

I followed the instruction within this article. 
[Auto-Deployment Using Bitbucket and Heroku](https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/auto-deployment-using-bitbucket-and-heroku-521b4271cc27)

My `pipeline.yml` file looks like this:

```
image: ruby:2.4.0
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        # set HEROKU_API_KEY and HEROKU_APP_NAME environment variables
        # set clone `depth: full' as described here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/Y9-5Mw
        name: Deploy to Heroku
        deployment: test   # set to test, staging or production
        # trigger: manual  # uncomment to have a manual step
        script:
          - git push https://heroku:$HerokuAPI@git.heroku.com/$HerokuName.git HEAD

definitions:
  caches:
    bundler: ./vendor
```

Comment: in production.rb , set `config.assets_precompile: true`

Comment: i already try that and it still not working, same error

Comment: do "RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile" then try to push code

Comment: this may help youhttps://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and when I delete the pubic folder then `$rake assets:precompile` then `$git add -A $git commit -m "commit`" `$git push heroku master`